# Start_urls not getting parsed

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

The code below is pretty close to what you would see in most tutorials when working with `Scrapy's` `FormRequest`, but for some reason, no matter what variation I try, I can't seem to get it to work. It's my understanding (and maybe I'm dead wrong) that `start_url` is supposed to basically hand off to the `parse` function, which starts the process of scraping a site. Whenever I run this script, it just sets `start_url` to be the URL and then treats `parse` like an uncalled function (skipping it). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's driving me nuts!!

```
import requests
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

def authentication_failed(response):
# TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if it failed
# or False if it succeeded.
pass 
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'example.com'
   start_urls = ["https://app.hubspot.com/login"]

   def parse(self, response):
      f=open("/PATH/auth.txt","r")
      lines=f.readlines()
      username=lines[0]
      password=lines[1]
      f.close() 
      yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'email': username, 'password': password},
        callback=self.after_login(self,response)
    )

   def after_login(self, response):
      if authentication_failed(response):
          self.logger.error("Login failed")
          return
```

Comment: post output of code

Comment: There isn’t anything to post. The script returns nothing, otherwise I would have posted it. Script runs, then finished with no errors, no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getting passed to parse function, and this is the page:
[image]

It's using Javascript to check your browser, try using a headless browser.

Comment: I’m curious as to how you can tell this? When I run the above script, I get nothing and when I put breakpoints on during debugging, it never breaks within the parse method.

Comment: You can open it with scrapy shell and then type 'view(response)' to see it in browser, or add to your code: 'from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
            inspect_response(response, self)' [see here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses)